# Can someone explain the use of last two things in given code

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct Interval {
     int start;
     int end;
     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};
```

I understood `int start` and `int end` but can anyone please describe what other two things represent.

Comment: What do the C++ books you are using say what those two lines are?  If you're not using C++ books, and instead learning C++ by trial and error, C++ is not a computer language that lends itself in learning in that fashion.  It is one of the most difficult computer languages out there.

Comment: Check out some reference to [constructors and member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: if you're learning *anything* by trial and error alone, it's likely to be a long path :-)

Comment: The problem with this question is that it is not focused.  We have no idea what part of those two lines you do not understand.  It could be anything from why `Interval` is used there, what the `:` means, why a function can be defined inside a `struct`, anything.  This is why a good C++ book is better to explain these things in detail than an answer post in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}`

This is an empty constructor which initializes the value of `start` and `end` to `0`.

`Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}`

This is another constructor which takes two values as parameters and sets the value of `start` to `s` and sets the value of `end` to `e`

Comment: What is the need of two constructors? Constructor assigning start and end values to zero is useless isin't it?

Comment: The constructor that takes no arguments is called the "default constructor".  In many cases, code will not compile unless the class has a default constructor.

Comment: @Tom, if you don't set the values of your fields they may end up being uninitialized (it depends on their type but for `int`s that's exactly what would happen) which is a risk of running into undefined behavior. Therefore, setting their values to zero makes a lot of sense because when you create your object, you know what its state is and you know what kind of behavior you can expect from that object.